# ionic framework append data to array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
firedata = firebase.database().ref('/chatusers/');    
postData(val){    
items=[];
this.items.push(val);
      this.firedata.child(this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid).update({
        uid: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid,
        post: this.items,
        displayName: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.displayName
      })
 })
```

I am trying to push my data to firebase, so everytime the funtion postData is called i want my array `items=[]` to keep appending with the data `val`.
At the moment its just overwriting with the new value.
I am new to `ionic3` so please help me.

```
expected output:
---post
      0: 'A'
      1: 'B'
      2: 'C'
uid:
-----------------------------------------------

Code with ionic3 storage


    firedata = firebase.database().ref('/chatusers/');    
        postData(val){
    var uniqueUID = this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid;

    let toaster = this.toastCtrl.create({
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });

    if(this.userdata.title==""){
      toaster.setMessage("Please fill out the title");
      toaster.present();
    }

    this.storage.get('Task1-'+uniqueUID).then((item)=> {
      if (item != null) {
        item.push(val);
        this.storage.set('Task1-'+uniqueUID, item);
      }
      else {
        let array = [];
        array.push(val);
        this.storage.set('Task1-'+uniqueUID, array);
      }
      this.items.push(val);
      this.firedata.child(this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid).update({
        uid: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid,
        post: item,
        displayName: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.displayName
      })

    })

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it outside the `myMethod()` as shown below.

```
items:any=[];

constructor(){

}

myMethod(){

    firedata = firebase.database().ref('/chatusers/');    
    postData(val){    

    this.items.push(val);
      this.firedata.child(this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid).update({
        uid: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid,
        post: this.items,
        displayName: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.displayName
      })
 })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. So basically when I switch the tab to some other tab it just overwrites. Not appending in the list manner as I want in firebase.

Comment: Oh.. You didn't tell about page movements no? You need to use Ionic Storage module for that.See that and let me know if you need more help: http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: I did the storage part and it did work, But the problem what i encountered was that the same data was getting stored for all the users. I've posted the code for ionic storage. check

Comment: Then you need to keep `dynamic key` according to the `user` like this: `this.storage.set('Task-'+ userId, array);`. That is it.

Comment: Thought so. Worked!!
One doubt, I am not able to see my array[0] on firebase, but when I make another post, it gets displayed with array[1] and array[0]. why so?

Comment: What are you doing here? Don't you have any compile-time errors `if (item != null) {
        item.push(val);
        this.storage.set('Task1-'+uniqueUID, item);
      }`